# How do I install openssl for Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, openssl

This is driving me crazy. Endless google searches yield zero help for what should be a simple task. I have a ruby script that requires the 'openssl' library, a script that was previously working before I upgraded my Ruby build to 2.2.2. This messed all my existing ruby stuff up, so I rolled back to my original version of 1.9.3, and openssl is now gone. I tried

```
gem install 'openssl'
```

and a bunch of other variations, but this simply throws the error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'openssl' in any repository
```

Can anybody tell me how I can get openssl back in my Ruby installation?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/HatemMahmoud/1200482

Comment: Are you using a version manager like [RVM](http://rvm.io/)? Also why are you installing `openssl` as a gem when it's built in to Ruby?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying `ruby-build`, which is a ruby installer.

Even if you don't plan to use it long-term, it's good about installing all the dependencies, such as SSL. If ruby-build succeeds for you, then you can look at its logs to see how it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my question was a silly one that didn't even make sense. Openssl wasn't the problem, and I was able to fix my own issue. If an admin could close or even delete this thread, that would probably be best for everybody.

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question if that's necessary, or you can explain how you fixed it here and share your findings with other people that might have the same problem.